# Excel - Freezing a formula

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create a spreadsheet, where on one sheet I have data (to which I will add a new row with new figures each week) and on another sheet, a summary of the most recent 4 weeks using `=SHEET1!B4:C4` as a formula (for example).

How can I lock that formula so that (in Sheet 1) when I add a new row for a new week, the formula doesnt adjust to `=SHEET1!B5:C5`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Following your comment I think I understand. You will need the OFFSET function anchored to the latest datum.

See the is walk through: http://excelsemipro.com/2010/10/the-offset-function-last-7-data-points/

and [this tutorial](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/09/17/offset-formula-explained/) shows more info

To Lock data:

```
=SHEET1!B4:C4
```

should be replaced with

```
=SHEET1!$B$4:$C$4
```

Here's some further notes: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rextang/archive/2007/06/07/3136694.aspx

Comment: Hi Preet - thanks for your help. Unfortunately, using the $ only locked the formula to the data - not the cell location. For example, when I inserted the $ through F4, and then went back into sheet 1 and inserted a row above - the formula in the first cell (that I had "locked") changed to =SHEET1!$B$5:$C$5. I need it to still pull data from B4:C4 - irrespective of the data that is in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

To lock a formula against a row, column, or cell, use the `$` before the row/column. `=SHEET1!$B$4:$C$4` will lock both row and column, if you just need to lock the rows, then use `=SHEET1!B$4:C$4`.

Alternatively, you can name the range (in your case a single cell), see here: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm